# How to swipe images both on left and right swipe?

Tags: android, swipe-gesture

I want to change images on touch of each image.
Total image count=3 where the url is stored in url[],   but my problem is that its just swiping inbetween two images only.

```
holder.llRecommendation.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeDismissTouchListener(
                     holder.llRecommendation,
                     null,
                     new SwipeDismissTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                         @Override
                         public boolean canDismiss(Object token) {
                             return true;
                         }

                         @Override
                         public void onDismiss(View view, Object token) {



                                 if(touch>0)
                                    {


                                          touch--;
                                            loader.displayFullImage(url[touch], holder.imgRecommendationBelow);
                             }


                                 else if(touch<2)
                                    {



                                          touch++;
                                            loader.displayFullImage(url[touch], holder.imgRecommendationBelow);
                                    }

                              /*Toast.makeText(mParentActivity, ""+SwipeDismissTouchListener.touch, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();                    

                                loader.displayFullImage(url[SwipeDismissTouchListener.touch], holder.imgRecommendationBelow);*/
                            // dismissableContainer.removeView(dismissableButton);
                         }
                     }));
```

Comment: try to use viewpager.

Comment: No I cannnot use view pager ,since the view is a  child view of exapndable listview. and its not advisable to use viewpager as achildeviw inside listview